# Understadning C# delegate Func<...> operators

Tags: c#, function, delegates

I am having some trouble on understanding some C# Func<...> operators, for example, we have the following snippet:

```
Func<int, bool> a = n => n <= 1;
Func<int, int> b = n => 10;
Func<int, int> c = n => { return n; };
Func<int, int> d = n => a(n)? b(n): n*c(n-1);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", d(1), d(2), d(3));
```

What is the meaing of `?` and `:` stand for ? is `a(n)? b(n)` stand for a condition ? (e.g. if `a(n)` is false and b(n) has value, calculate c(n) and return it as `d`.) I am not sure if I understand this correctly or is my assumption are totally wrong.

Comment: That's the ternary operator, nothing special about it there.

Comment: @jdphenix Thanks, didn't know they are called ternary operator.

Comment: It's all good, it's difficult to google for `?:` :D

Comment: @jdphenix Yup, Wiki has a very detail explanation about this, sorry for asked a dump question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more clear, you can interpret

```
n => a(n)? b(n): n*c(n-1);
```

as (given the definitions provided at your question):

```
if (n<=1)
    return 10; //b(n)
else
    return n*n-1; //n*c(n-1)=n*n
```

Notice that `returns` are there because of `d=...`

Comment: Ternary operator is not the same as if-else statement.

Comment: @DannyChen sure it's not. Who said it is?